# Get text from one element, display in another

Tags: regex, string, substr

I'm trying to get a specific segment from a block of text and display it in a new child element. The challenge I'm facing is, the month/day is dynamic. I only need to get the month/day/year. BUT, I need to display it using this format "May 4, 2018".

Here's the text I'm referring to:

> Canceling your reservation before 6:00 PM (local hotel time) on
>   Monday, 11 June, 2018 will result in no charge.

I haven't worked with regexp or strings much, so I'm not sure where to go from here. That said, here's some code I've started with. When executing it, I'm getting an **Uncaught ReferenceError: locale is not defined**.

```
var cancelPolicyText = "Canceling your reservation before 6:00 PM (local hotel time) on Monday, 11 June, 2018 will result in no charge. ";
var cpRegex =  / on (.*) will/;
var cpDateString = cpRegex.exec(cancelPolicyText)[1];
var cpDate = new Date(cpDateString);
var month = cpDate.toLocaleString(locale, { month: "long" });
var newFormatDate = cpDate.getDate() + " " + month + ", " + cpDate.getFullYear();
newFormatDate
```

Any help/guidance is appreciated.

- Brion

Comment: should be tagged as javascript?

Answer (score 0):

`locale` is undefined so change :

```
var month = cpDate.toLocaleString(locale, { month: "long" });
```

To a validate locale (for example `en-GB`) :

```
var month = cpDate.toLocaleString('en-GB', { month: "long" });
```

And to obtain the format you are looking for, change :

```
var newFormatDate = cpDate.getDate() + " " + month + ", " + cpDate.getFullYear();
```

To :

```
var newFormatDate = month + " " + cpDate.getDate() + ", " + cpDate.getFullYear();
```

Result :

```js
var cancelPolicyText = "Canceling your reservation before 6:00 PM (local hotel time) on Monday, 11 June, 2018 will result in no charge. ";
var cpRegex =  / on (.*) will/;
var cpDateString = cpRegex.exec(cancelPolicyText)[1];
var cpDate = new Date(cpDateString);
var month = cpDate.toLocaleString('en-GB', { month: "long" });
var newFormatDate = month + " " + cpDate.getDate() + ", " + cpDate.getFullYear();
console.log(newFormatDate);
```